# Deploying an Angular Universal App in Azure web app service - Linux based

Tags: angular, azure, azure-devops, pm2

I'm trying to deploy an `Angular Universal App` in `Azure web app service (Linux webapp)` using `azure devops pipeline` and build/release pipeline are successfully completed. Please see below screenshot.

[image: Build Pipeline]

[image: Release pipeline]

Also, I tried to add this ***pm2 serve /home/site/wwwroot -no-daemon-spa*** in `startup command` for `Azure Application Setting` but no luck. I am still not able to accesss my angular webapp page. When I try to access Azure web app it's loading default azure webapp page.

[image: Command sreenshot]

when I check Azure Web App `Application logs`, I found this -

> Platform logs contain errors or warnings
>
> Container webapp_2_547df8bc didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 8080, failing site start Container webapp_2_547df8bc for site webapp has exited, failing site start

Kindly suggest if some one has any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending couple of hours on this, I was able to deploy this app using Azure pipeline after making below change in server.ts file -

```
const distFolder = join(process.cwd(), 'dist/app_name/browser');
```

And changing `startup command` for `Azure Application Setting` from `pm2 serve /home/site/wwwroot -no-daemon-spa` to `node /home/site/wwwroot/dist/app_name/server/main.js`

Comment: In Angular, there is no server.ts

Comment: in angular universal there should be a server thingy (ssr)

Comment: Where I can find this "/home/site/wwwroot -no-daemon-spa" ??

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me without adding any changes in Angular, simply updated the below command in `App services(Web app Linux) -> configuration -> Startup command`

```
pm2 serve /home/site/wwwroot --spa --no-daemon
```

Comment: Can't find Startup command in Configuration. Can you show screen shot please